# Using an in-memory db with pgx and bun (Golang)

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx, bun

I have just started using [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) and [bun](https://bun.uptrace.dev/) with Golang and I need to start testing my repository implementation. I am struggling to understand if I can use an embedded postgres db and what would be the best choice. Any suggestion is more than welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL cannot run as an embedded database. It can run as in-memory database, however, if you give it enough memory.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. Would you have any example to point me to for an in-memory databse that I can use? I have started using https://bun.uptrace.dev/ and it has a nice features called ```fixtures```: https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/fixtures.html#creating-fixtures: https://github.com/uptrace/bun/blob/master/example/fixture/main.go and perhaps this might be a nice way to go? What is your view?

Comment: I have no overview, and asking for recommendations for software is off topic. But it sure ain't PostgreSQL.

Comment: OK, not an issue. However, I clearly stated that I am using pgx and bun in my question, so I do not see this can be construed as off topic. Besides, my question is tagged with both pgx and bun

Comment: I agree - I was talking about the question you asked in your comment, not your original question.